# Classical Mechanics - Equation of motion, Lagrangian, Newtons 2nd Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I really don't even know where to start with this question.

> A particle with charge $q$ moving in an electromagnetic field is described by the Lagrangian $$L=\frac{m\mathrm v^2}2+\frac qc\mathrm v\cdot\mathrm A(\mathrm r,t)-q\phi(\mathrm r,t)$$
>
> The electric and magnetic fields ($\mathrm E(\mathrm r,t)$ and $\mathrm B(\mathrm r,t)$ correspondingly) are related to ‘potentials’ $\mathrm A(\mathrm r,t)$ and $\phi(\mathrm r,t)$ introduces above as follows:
>
> $$\mathrm E=-\frac1c\frac{\partial\mathrm A}{\partial t}-\nabla\phi,\quad\mathrm B=\nabla\times\mathrm A$$
>
> Using the identity $$\mathrm {v\times(\nabla\times A)=\nabla(v\cdot A)-(-v\cdot\nabla)A}$$
>
> (a) find the equation of motion of the charged particle from the Lagrangian. (5 marks)
>
> (b) express the force acting on the particle in terms of electric and magnetic fields only (i.e. the equation of motion should have the form of the Newton's second law and contain fields $\mathrm E$ and $\mathrm B$ but not the ‘potentials’ $\mathrm A$ and $\mathrm\phi$).

Answer (score 1):

Write out the Lagrangian in component form, i.e., $L = \sum_i m\tfrac{\dot x_i^2}{2} + \dots$ and apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to it. Reassemble in vector form and use the identities. Unless you are comfortable with notation like $\tfrac{\delta L}{\delta \vec{v}}$, in which case you can just apply the Euler-Lagrange equations right away.